# java File.delete() dosent work for rename file

Tags: file, rename, delete-file

why this code dont work correct? file a.txt is create on hard disk and then a.txt rename to b.txt but b.txt will not delete.

```
import java.io.File;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File f=new File("a.txt");
        try {

            f.createNewFile();
        }
        catch (Exception e){}

        f.renameTo(new File("b.txt"));

        f.delete();
    }
}
```

If the line

```
f.renameTo(new File("b.txt"));
```

is removed, `f.delete();` works correctly and a.txt is deleted from hard disk.

Comment: You should log more info and not hidding Exception. Try closing the file "b.txt". Extrernalize b File b=new File("b.txt"). Also you could test file existence before delete...

Comment: file "b.txt" is closed and exist on hard but not delete..

Comment: So like Hamid said I would try to see if another process is locking the file. But provide more info. It's hard to tell without any error.

Answer (score 0):

The `delete` method will not work if :

- The file doesn't exist
- The file is open by another process (editor, ..)
- You dont't have privileges to delete it.

Could you provide the error stack to analyze?

Comment: every thing is ok but code doesn't work !!  no error on console but b.txt not delete. try code...